# Eclipse modifies server.xml each time run the project (Run-->Run on Server)

Tags: eclipse, settings, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I'm using Tomcat 7 on Eclipse Juno. I use workspace metadata as server location (Please see my tomcat configurations below).

[image: Tomcat configurations]

Also I got a **Server project** in eclipse [please see the image below] with separate server.xml and other configuration files.

[image: Server project]

Normally it works fine. The issue came across after I changed the server.xml (in eclipse project) for SSL configurations.

Configurations are working fine. But each time I run the project (Run-->Run on Server) server.xml get modified to the default version. My customized SSL changes are missing.

Also I tried to change server.xml in tomcat installation location (C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\conf), but it didn't pick from eclipse.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an applicable solution but not a perfect one.

What I have done is;

1.Changed server.xml file in installation location (In my case C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\conf)

2.Remove tomcat server  from eclipse server panel (please see the image below)

3.Create a new server in eclipse server panel.

4.Then Server project will be generated new server.xml with my customized changes.

5.The trick is, initially eclipse picks server.xml from installation location when create a new server in panel.

Thanks

[image: eclipse server panel]

Comment: Any alternative suggestions please…

Comment: Check out my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: I suggest the solution offered by Exocom! Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In **{workspace}/Servers** you will find a folder for every Tomcat configuration, containing several configuration files, including the **server.xml**. There you then can **edit the file** directly.

To get changes taken into account **restart Eclipse**. That is imho better than removing and adding the configuration back all the time. Tested using Eclipse **Mars** and **Tomcat 7**.

(the solution is from: [Eclipse with tomcat - eclipse modifies server.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485760/eclipse-with-tomcat-eclipse-modifies-server-xml))

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are editing the files right beneath the tomcat server folder, not the ones beneath the config folder. Check the attached screenshot for the files I'm referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and the solution worked (I don't have enough reputation points to vote up the answer).

On a similar note, I had to make configuration changes to a port number and that also required me to delete and re-add my tomcat instance from STS (spring tool suite).

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse, double click on Server to view properties.
check "publish module contexts to separate XML files", and save it.
Run Tomcat server.
Eclipse will be create conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[appname].xml without touching server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path in the server.xml is same as in the Web project Settings.

To see the Web Project Settings: Right click on the project >> Properties >> Web Project Settings.

Always give the project path over here. The path in server.xml will automatically updated.

Answer (score -1):

Clean Tomcat Work Directory & Republish the project.

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?